# How do I give the list an index name?

Tags: python, list

I've seen something like this construction somewhere:

```
list.append({
   'title': scName,
   'link': scLink,
})

print('Names:', list['title'])
print('Links:', list['link'])
```

Can you please show a working example?

Comment: You are describing a `dict` not a `list`

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. In any case, it is **never** going to be possible to use a `str` object to index a `list` object. You can use a dictionary of course, but it seems like you are already aware of that?

Comment: "like this construction". No you didn't. Show what you actually saw, or better yet, read the tutorial.

Comment: What specifically is not "working" with the code you've shown? Where did you "see" this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the dict is being appended to a list. And to use inner data, we've to put `list[<index_of_inner_dict>][key_of_that_data]`. In short, we've to go to the whole inner data index, then the index of required value. Here we have only one dict, it is simply list[0]. Also, scName and scLink are not defined, I'm assuming that they are simple strings. Your code:

```
l=[]
l.append({
   'title': "scName",
   'link': "scLink"
})
print (l)

print('Names:', l[0]['title'])       
print('Links:', l[0]['link'])
```

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you are asking is for someone to give you an example of how to use a dictionary. To give some background on dictionaries, they store information in key-value pairs. The key, which is the "index name" you mentioned in your title is mapped to a value stored. You can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) if you are still confused.

For the code example you gave, what it looks like you are attempting to do is add multiple dictionaries to a list and then access those values. Here is an example.

```
lst_of_employees = []

lst_of_employees.append({"name": "John", "salary": "10000"})
lst_of_employees.append({"name": "Jane", "salary": "20000"})

for emp in lst_of_employees:
    print(f"{emp['name']} makes ${emp['salary']} a year.")
```

You can make the value of the key-value pair whatever you would like. Here is an example with the value stored at the key "salary" as another dictionary.

```
lst_of_employees = []

lst_of_employees.append({"name": "John", "salary": {"base": 8000, "bonus": 2000}})
lst_of_employees.append({"name": "Jane", "salary": {"base": 15000, "bonus": 5000}})

for emp in lst_of_employees:
    employee = emp["name"]
    base = emp["salary"]["base"]
    bonus = emp["salary"]["bonus"]

    print(f"{emp['name']} makes ${base+bonus} a year.")
```